# Double information in definition of function

Tags: functions, notation

In a math book I have to read, the definition of a function is shown similar to this:
$$X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$e\mapsto X(e) \in \mathbb{R}$$
According to my understanding, the first line defines a function $X$, which takes one argument from the set $\Omega$ and produces some real number. Now the second line tells, when I take an $e$ and apply the function $X$, the result will be a real number.

Now, my question is: What is the purpose of the second line? Do I get any information, which was not already in the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we don't get any new information from the second line.

However, if $X(e)$ in the second line were replaced with something like $100$ or $|e|$, then we will get new information (i.e. what the function actually outputs
).